# Gnome panel missing application icons, chat bubble menu, and power menu

Tags: ubuntu, notifications, gnome-panel, gnome2

I've been messing around with my system too much and messed something up. I'm new to Ubuntu, but have been using linux on servers for a few years. I'm not sure of the correct terminology so I'm including screen shots to explain what is going on.

First, system specs:

> Ubuntu 10.4 LTS x64 Lucid
>   Core i7-970
>   Nvidia GTX 480
>   Dual Screen with Twinview
>   Nvidia proprietary dev driver 260.24 (64-bit)

Now what I screwed up:

First major customization was `ppa:goehle/goehle-ppa` customizations for keeping evolution open after closing the main window. That worked fine until I started messing with getting hibernate working.

I never got hibernate working even after installing `linux-generic-tuxonice`; it gave a warning about usb09 not stopping. The only things that I have in USB are a keyboard and mouse.

Then I started getting the error:

[image: The panel encountered a problem while loading "OAFIID:GNOME_FastUserSwitchApplet"]

Trying to fix this, I reinstalled the Evolution customizations. The error persists and now the panel is messed up as well. I'm not getting the application icons, the menu with the chat status, or the shutdown/restart/lock screen menu.

This is what it should look like:

[image: Expected panel]

But this is what I'm getting now:

[image: Actual panel]

How do I get my icons back?

---

**EDIT:** I found how to get my application icons back.

1. Right-click on panel
2. Add to Panel ...
3. Notification Area.

I still have not figured out what the chat bubble menu and power menu are called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Power thingy and the user chat bubble thingy are both the same applet called "Indicator Applet Session".

Comment: The INdicator Applet gives the sound mail and music player icons, but I'm still not getting the power or chat bubble.  Do I have some setting wrong?

Comment: That's what the "Indicator Applet" does. There is also "Indicator Applet Session" which provides "chat bubble" and "power". If it got removed by accident: The package is called "indicator-applet-session"

Answer (score 1):

the required package is "indicator-applet-me" (chat bubble on the right top corner)